# JPA Multiple Like and AND clasues

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am new to JPA, how Can I convert bellow SQL statement to JPA statement?

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE (CustomerName LIKE '%Chitta%' OR Address LIKE '%Permanent%') AND Country = "UK" AND City = "London";
```

My Customers table has following attributes -

```
CustomerID, CustomerName ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country
```

I am using

> "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"

Comment: Try looking at [Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

Comment: Since you're using Spring data you could also keep using those SQL statements on your repositories or convert them to [JPQL](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL). When using query methods have a look at the [`@Query` documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)  which already provides an example for a `like` expression. Then just add the rest like you'd do in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following below query to work with. Also native query true help you run the native SQL query. If you are providing the parameter through the method argument then use this query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE (CustomerName LIKE %:cname% OR Address LIKE %:add%) AND Country = :country AND City = :city",nativeQuery = true)
List<Customers> getListCustomers(@Param("cname")String CustomerName,@Param("add") String Address, @Param("country") String, @Param("city")String City)
```

If you are hardcoding the fields then you can directly use your query in JPA.

For more understanding regarding the JPA query go through this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query)

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working.
How to make this like statement IgnoreCase?

Comment: To make it case Insensitive you can pass the parameter in lowercase or uppercase just like (String address.toLowerCase()) and also Compare in JPA query ( LOWER(Address) LIKE %:add%), also you can compare both in Uppercase.

Comment: can you please take a look on this one once?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292744/jpa-like-and-and-in-clause