# JPA LIKE and and IN clause

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

New to JPA, I have two entity and a joining table like below -

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "classes")
public class ClassDao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Column(length = 5120)
    private String description;

   
    @ManyToMany
    @ToStringExclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JoinTable(name = "db_joint_table__class_activities",
            joinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
            inverseJoinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<ActivityDao> activities;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity")
public class ActivityDao {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;


    @ManyToMany
    @ToStringExclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @JoinTable(name = "db_joint_table__class_activities",
            joinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", referencedColumnName = "id") },
            inverseJoinColumns =
                    { @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    private Set<ClassDao> classes;
}
```

and two repositories like -

```
public interface ClassRepo extends JpaRepository<ClassDao, Long> {
}

public interface ActivityRepo extends JpaRepository<ActivityDao, Long> {
}
```

I like to make a SQL like query(**with pagination** ) -

```
SELECT * FROM classes WHERE (classes.name LIKE %SEARCH_TERM% OR classes.description LIKE %SEARCH_TERM%) 
AND QUERY_ACTIVITY IN classes.activities;
```

SEARCH_TERM = dynamic input to search query.
QUERY_ACTIVITY = an Activity, dynamic input to search query.

**Expected** - search will return classes which contains SEARCH_TERM in it's `name` or `description` and contains the QUERY_ACTIVITY in it's `activities` attribute.

How to do it?

If I try like bellow -

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM classes WHERE (lower(title) LIKE %:titlePhrase% OR lower(description)" +
        " LIKE %:descriptionPhrase%) AND :activityDao IN activities", nativeQuery = true)
Page<ClassDao> findClassWithActivityNew(@Param("titlePhrase") String titlePhrase, @Param("descriptionPhrase")
String descriptionPhrase, @Param("activityDao") ActivityDao activityDao, Pageable pageable);
```

I am getting bellow error -

```
2022-08-10 10:16:06,945 WARN  [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2022-08-10 10:16:06,945 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: syntax error at or near "activities"
  Position: 92
2022-08-10 10:16:06,956 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] com.markany.anyfit.server.rest.BaseController: handleException():
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:259)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
```

Comment: you cannot pass a list as a parameter on the right side of an 'in' clause. Try working your query the other way around, so that your search parameters are in the 'in' clause. Try JPQL of the form "select distinct c from classes join c.activities activity where (c.name = :searchTerm OR c.description = :searchTerm) and activity in (:searchList)" and see if that matches what you want

Comment: I guess the line means "contains all of QUERY_ACTIVITY_LIST in it's activities attribute." just fetch all the activities, regards less any `IN` condition.

Comment: @Chris thank you so much for your replay, I have modified the requirement. Now only one activity will be passed to query, now, what will be the right query?

Comment: Try "select c from  classes c where :searchActivity in c.activities and .."

Comment: @Chris - Thanks.
But, it does not work. As of now, I am using joints like - 

@Query(
            value = "SELECT * FROM classes c, db_joint_table__class_activities jt, activity a " +
                    "WHERE c.id=jt.class_id AND jt.activity_id=a.id AND :activityId=a.id " +
                    "AND (lower(c.title) like %:titlePhrase% OR lower(c.description) LIKE %:descriptionPhrase%)",
            nativeQuery = true)

Comment: I've been giving you JPQL query strings, not SQL ones: 'activities' doesn't exist in SQL. Try using JPQL by removing the 'nativeQuery = true' indicator. If you have problems and want to use Native SQL, check out what SQL is executed by JPA for a similar JPQL query first, so you can see the data it expects and how it handles joins for fetching, and use that as a basis for your own SQL.